# How to Find Real Disposable Income for Iran?

Tags: macroeconomics, national-income, basic-income

I'm doing a project for my macro course, and I'm trying to find real disposable income for Iran over a 25 year period. In my course Disposable income, $Y_d = Y - T$, where $Y$ is output (income) and $T$ is taxes. I've been to the IMF and World Bank websites and have had no success in finding a disposable income indicator. Can someone please help me? Thank You!!

Comment: I would also ensure that you are taking into account that **real** disposable income is nominal disposable income divided by price level. And (as outlined in an edit I've posted) that $Y$ is output or income and that you should look for income in this particular case. You will likely have to find data on income, price levels, and taxes over the 25 year period. As for _where_ to find these, I am unable to help so I will only leave this constructive comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: @Brennan Hey thanks for the reply. I went to the Central Bank of Iran and found data for the period I need. I've found data for GNP, depreciation, and indirect taxes. GNP - Dep - I.T. = Personal Income. To get personal disposable income I need to subtract direct (income) taxes; but I can't find that indicator here. Is there another way of finding it that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Hmm I am unsure, maybe look for some kind of marginal tax rate or other and just multiply it by your personal income for each period to great a value of taxation in each period then subtract it from the personal income. Not sure where to find the tax rate and it would be weird because I imagine income taxes scale with how much you make in Iran?

Comment: @Brennan Thanks. I just talked to my professor and he said that other students were able to find the disposable income metric directly in the world bank data set. I've been searching like crazy and haven't been able to find it.

Comment: All that I've found is [this](https://databank.worldbank.org/reports.aspx?source=2&country=IRN) but I can't seem to find the disposable income metric either. Maybe its somewhere else? Sorry I can't help further

Comment: @Brennan Thanks for trying! I'll keep going. Everything is riding on this metric so I gotta make it happen. Thanks again.